# Global variable that points to the location of an element in a global array (in C)

Tags: c, arrays, global-variables, symbols

Let's say we have an array defined as a global variable.

```
int array[] = {16, 25, 36, 49, 64};
```

If this is compiled as a shared library, compiler will produce a binary with a symbol "array" pointing to the location in memory of the array.

Is it possible to add a global variable that will represent a memory location that is inside of the array.

```c
int elem;
```

Can it be some how made that elem represents the same location as array[2]? Is that even possible with just C?

**EDIT:**

Can it be done without involving pointers? I am interested into making elem *being* the location in memory at witch array[2] resides. With `int* elem = &array[2]` memory is set aside for a pointer and elem becomes a symbol for that pointer, and then the memory adress of array[2] is put in there. I would like that elem becomes a symbol for a location of array[2], so that `assert(elem == array[2])` would pass **always**. Like an identity in math (≡).

Does anybody know is the thing I am interested in possible in plain C, or only in assembly.

Comment: :D __Is that even possible with just C?__

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is impossible in plain C without using a pointer.

You can, however, use some linker trickery to achieve this (beware that this is not portable and very, very hacky): Get your default linker script from `ld -verbose` and edit it to include something like `elem = (array) + 4 * 2;`, then compile with `-Wl,-Tyour_script.ld`. `elem` should now occupy the same memory address as `array` + 8 Bytes (which is `array[2]` assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`):

```
 $ cat a.c
 #include <stdio.h>

 int foo[4] = {1,2,3,4};

 int bar;

 int main() {
    printf("%p %p\n", &foo[2], &bar);
    return 0;
 }
 $ gcc -Wl,-Ta.ld a.c
 $ ./a.out
 0x6008e8 0x6008e8
 $
```

Comment: This is the kind of answer I was looking for. I'll vote you up when I get the rep for it. :)

Comment: @iRasic or you could click the check mark beside this answer to mark it as the answer for the question (which you should do on some answer anyway)

Answer (score 4):

Sure:

```
// lib.c

int array[] = { 1, 2, 3 };
int * const p = array + 2;
```

```
// lib.h

extern int array[];
extern int * const p;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
int array[] = {16, 25, 36, 49, 64};

int *elem = array + n;
```

Answer (score 1):

An ugly preprocessor hack allows you to use ELEM2 just like array[2]. In fact it *is* array[2] :

```
int array[] = {16, 25, 36, 49, 64};
#define ELEM2 (array[2])
```

Now ELEM2 is even an lvalue:

```
ELEM2 = 42;

int *p = &ELEM2;

/* don't try this at home */
```

BTW Though this is ugly, it is basically how stdin, stdout  and stderr are #defined in most implementations (in fact: all the implementations I have seen)

UPDATE: although it is an ugly hack, it does enable the compiler to catch aliasing problems like this:

```
array[2] = ELEM2++ * array[2]; /* no intervening sequence points here */
```

Comment: This kind of thing is how `errno` is usually defined, too - a macro that behaves like an lvalue.  There's nothing wrong with this - it should work just as well as the linker trick (except that `array` has to be visible to the code using `ELEM2`), and is portable.

Comment: Well, actually it is more robust than the linker trick (aliasing ...).

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
int * elem = &array[2];
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can

```
int array[] = {16, 25, 36, 49, 64};
int * elem = &array[2];

int main()
{
    printf("array: %p elem: %p", array, elem);
    return 0;
}
```